# Control layout object in fragment - getting null object reference

Tags: java, android, fragment

I made a fragment_console.xml and ConsoleFragment.java
In MainActivity.java I create object `console_fragment = new ConsoleFragment();`
Then OnClickListener runs `console_fragment.method();`

But it gives error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`
on line

`sendButton = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_send_button);`

ConsoleFragment.java

```
public class ConsoleFragment extends Fragment {

View v;
private boolean isVisible;

private Button sendButton;
private TextView consoleText;
private EditText commandText;

public ConsoleFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_console, container, false);
    showConsole(v);
    return v;
}



public void showConsole(View v){
    sendButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_send_button);
    consoleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_log_text);
    commandText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_command_text);

    isVisible = true;
    sendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    consoleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    commandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ConsoleFragment console_fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    console_fragment = new ConsoleFragment();
}

public void triggerConsole(View view) { //buton on click
    console_fragment.showConsole(view);
}
}
```

fragment_console.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".activities.ConsoleFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_console_log_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_console_command_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/console_command"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_console_send_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/console_send_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/activity_top_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.wordfall.wordfallcontroll.activities.ConsoleFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/activity_bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to get layout object (buttons, tv etc) to get control on it in fragment class?

Comment: you are getting this error because you you haven't passed view in that method.

Comment: the v represent your layout fragment_x and this layout should contain a Button with id: fragment_console_send_button.

Comment: If it is java, `v.findViewById` returns `T` object, so you must cast it to the specific view like Button, TextView, EditText.

Comment: @RudraRokaya yes, layout fragment_x has a button with id fragment_console_send_button 
I check with debuger - v equals to null - I tried to change it with getView() but it doesnt help

Comment: @grabarz121 tried that, but doesnt help

Comment: where you used debugger for v?. in this fragment or from another class?

Comment: In this fragment

Comment: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView -> this is also container. you are using two container, why?

Comment: without it app crash after start  `No view found for id 0x7f080087 (x:id/container) for fragment ConsoleFragment{77b211b}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XFragment extends Fragment {
 View v;
 private boolean isVisible;

private Button sendButton;
private TextView consoleText;
private EditText commandText;

public XFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_x, container, false);
   showConsole(v);
   return v;
}



public void showConsole(View v){
    sendButton = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_send_button);
    consoleText = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_log_text);
    commandText = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_command_text);

    isVisible = true;
    sendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    consoleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    commandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

In your activity_main.xml file you need to create a container for holding fragments like:

> activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
......
......
....
>
 .........
 ........
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your MainActivity.java file inside onCreate method you can do:

> MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(...){
   .....
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new ConsoleFragment(), "ConsoleFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Comment: It is not the way I need to do - I need to call showConsole from other class 
Anyways this solution gives the same error

Comment: use the above code and try to use a debugger for v. if this throws an error or not?

Comment: Yes, it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity on sendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: can you add more code?

Comment: Added more code to main post (after some tests)

Comment: does your activity_main has a container for holding fragment?

Comment: Yes it does, added activity_main.xml to main post

Answer (score 0):

What view you pass into triggerConsole method from outside fragment? The problem may be in this, you'll try to find controls in layout, which is not part of your fragment. View of your fragment is assigned to global variable `v`, but now you try to get it from method parameter named `v`. Try this code.

```
public void showConsole(){
    sendButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_send_button);
    consoleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_log_text);
    commandText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_console_command_text);

    isVisible = true;
    sendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    consoleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    commandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

If you want pass different layouts into same fragment, do it via constructor, not via method parameter, and each time make new instance of fragment.

Comment: Tried it already - getting error when showConsole is called
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`


When checking in debug mode v inside showConsole = null so there is a problem, but cant figure it out

Comment: View v is getting null when method OnCreateView(...) finishes... 
So here is the problem, but how to fix it?

Comment: I've checked your code, problem will be in button inside MainActivity, you cannot just call method from fragment to show it, you must do it by replace current view with fragment, what **Rudra Rokaya** did show you. Can you show button from MainActivity, where you call `triggerConsole` method?